# Copying Data from a hard drive to another hard drive with different partitioning

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, rsync

I have a System HardDrive - "sda", 64GB big with the following partitioning:

[image: IMG:]

sdb is a second harddrive, 128GB big, on which sda is cloned with rsync. It has only 1 partition, taking the full size of the hard drive.
sdc is a third harddrive, 2TB big, on which sda is backed up with rsnapshot.

In the case of my sda dying or going to be exchanged, what possibilities do i have to get the prior state back as safe and easy as possible with my 2 backup options.

Regarding the option that I have my sda cloned on sdb, is it possible to shift the data back on a new hard drive with different partitioning than the original sda?

Can I also just use sdb to be booted from?

Answer (score 0):

If SDB is a clone of SDA - forgoing the extra 64 gigs of space on it, yes, you can treat it as /dev/sda and boot from it.

Cloning, of-course, needs to be a bit copy and should be done offline.

(If you decide to rebuild your system, rebuild it on LVM - its a lot more flexible when it comes to resizing.  You might also want to consider having each partition as an mdadm RAID1 /(and ensuring both disks have appropriate boot sectors).

Comment: Well, it's not a bit copy in my case, it's file based with some expections i did not copy. But the /boot section is. Does the Bios/Uefi find the bootloader, if i mark the single sdb partition as boot, esp?

I was thinking about rebuilding the system, as it was starting as an experiment and started growing. I am currently dockerinzing all my applications to make them more portable. I will have a look at LVM.

Comment: BIOS should, I doubt UEFI does. Aldo, there is a boot sector you need to copy/write for booting - in BIOS at least this is not a file.